# Inverse_Transform and multistep data - how to scale and when

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I tried to ask this question [before](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/86786/inverse-of-the-maxminscalar), but I think it was difficult without revealing the full context.  Right now I'm tinkering with what I find online to informally learn about tensorflow before I formally learn it in the spring.

The [model](https://github.com/dlaj/test_stock) I have created takes normal open, high low, close, volume data and calculates a bunch of other features.  My intent is to use the prior 15 days of OHLCV+Technicals to predict the future 5 Close.

My issue is at the very end when I need to invert the model.predict.  Currently I am using the following workaround:

```
sc = MinMaxScaler()
test_set_tomorrow = dataset_train.iloc[-time_step:,:].values
scaled_test_set = sc.fit_transform(test_set_tomorrow)
scaled_test_set = test_set_tomorrow
X_test = []
for i in range (0,len(test_set_tomorrow)):
  X_test.append(scaled_test_set[i,:])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test=np.reshape(X_test,(1,time_step,-1))
predicted_price = model.predict(X_test)
predicted_price_fix = np.zeros(shape=(len(predicted_price), X_test.shape[2]))
predicted_price_fix[:,0:5]=predicted_price[:,0:5]
print(predicted_price_fix)
predicted_price=sc.inverse_transform(predicted_price_fix)
print(predicted_price)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
[[-0.04685311 -0.04455814 -0.04243669 -0.04118608 -0.03964855  0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.        ]]
[[ 1.56266435e+00  1.59385461e+00  1.49811773e+00  1.56682045e+00
   8.50910050e+05  1.65916667e+00  2.13096538e+00  1.60200000e+00
   1.63600000e+00  1.81628246e+00  2.08335540e+00 -3.99787353e-01
   6.99000000e-02  1.37914286e-01 -3.75699907e-01  1.00000000e+00
   2.61479727e+08  0.00000000e+00  2.01494297e+07  1.58000000e+00
   1.90910833e+00  1.76660253e-01 -4.35308886e+02 -2.06430382e-16
  -4.73584558e-18]]
```

There are two things which I find out.  The first is the values quite a bit off.  The second, is the fifth value.  It appears to be wildly out of whack.

Answer (score 1):

On the original code:

```
sc = MinMaxScaler()
test_set_tomorrow = dataset_train.iloc[-time_step:,:].values
```

Hm, you missed the shuffling, but it's OK -- maybe your data was shuffled earlier.

---

Original code:

```
scaled_test_set = sc.fit_transform(test_set_tomorrow)
```

The model should be trained on the train set not the test set - otherwise, data leakage occurs. It should be either:

```
sc.fit(dataset_train.iloc[:time_step])
scaled_test_set = sc.transform(test_set_tomorrow)
```

or

```
scaled_train_set = sc.fit_transform(train_set_tomorrow)
```

---

Original code:

```
scaled_test_set = test_set_tomorrow
```

You just erased all the pre-processing. If you check the data, `scaled_test_set` is exactly `dataset_train.iloc[-time_step:, :]`

---

Original code:

```
X_test = []
for i in range (0,len(test_set_tomorrow)):
  X_test.append(scaled_test_set[i,:])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test,(1,time_step,-1))
```

can be done quicker. Note that the `MinMaxScaler` returns the numpy array already.

```
X_test = np.expand_dims(scaled_test_set, axis=0)
```

---

Finally, you apply the inverse transform to the labels while training on the features. For example, consider the model where given height, we predict weight. You create a map that normalizes inches (or centimeters). In case of centimeters, say the smallest height is 150, but it is not true that the smallest weight is 150 kgs or pounds. Different scalers should be used.

Comment: Yes - this would be the prediction phase of looking at the last 15 steps to see the five out.  The shuffling did occur earlier.

Comment: Maybe I am missing it - but how does this address that the output is (1,5,23).  Isn't the scale of the transform dependent on the columns (features).  So the fifth value, which falls into the volume column, will have a very odd scale relative to it's value.

Comment: The scale of the transform is determine either by the train set or by the domain knowledge (e.g., images are scaled by 1/255) and should be part of the model.

Comment: In your code, the test set was not scaled at all, not even talking about the wrong scaling parameters. For example, if you had image whose pixel values are from 0 to 256 and you didn't scale it -- yes, you will get a ridiculous output. The solution is to fix the scaling.

Comment: I have made those changes.